# Hover over text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new here so hello to all. I was wondering if someone might be able to help. I have currently created a "Products" panel which gets all of the product information from a connected DB. Within my database I have a "ProductDescription" field which contains a few sentences about the products.

I was wondering if there was a way that when a user hovers over the Product Image that a text box (or something similar) would pop up with the description. Is this something that is possible?

[image]

I am completely new to this so sorry if it's silly question but I genuinely wouldn't have a foggest about where to start and this was just an idea I had. Would appreciate help where possible

**Panel Design**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlProducts" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" Width="625px" Font-Bold="false"
              Font-Italic="false" Font-Overline="false" Font-Strikeout="false" Font-Underline="false" Height="540px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div align="left">
            <table cellspacing="1" class="style4" style="border: 1px ridge #9900FF">
                <tr>
                    <td style="border-bottom-style: ridge; border-width: 1px; border-color: #000000" class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("ProductName") %>' Style="font-weight: 700"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img alt="" src='<%# Eval ("ProductImageUrl") %>' runat="server" id="imgProductImage" style="border: ridge 1px black; width: 173px; height: 160px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Price: £<asp:Label ID="lblProductPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("ProductPrice") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Image ID="imgTick" runat="server" Visible="false" ImageUrl="~/WebsiteImages/tick.png" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Stock Avaliability: <asp:Label ID="lblAvailableStock" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("AvailableStock") %>'
                                                       ToolTip="Available Stock " ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfProductID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval ("ProductID") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnAddToBasket" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval ("ProductID") %>'
                                    OnClick="BtnAddToBasket_Click" Text="Add to basket" Width="100%" BorderColor="Black"
                                    BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="1px" />

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="33%" />
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute on an HTML control becomes the hover text for that component.

```
<img title="Your Hover Text" ...
```

If you're using the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) framework, you can create much more attractive hover text by also setting the `data-toggle` and `data-placement` attributes.

Here is a link to a [helpful tutorial](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-tooltips.php) that gives the latter subject a thorough treatment.

**EDIT:**

Speaking to your additional question below, and assuming you have setup `ProductDescription` with the same accessibility in your code behind as you have setup `ProductImageUrl`, you would add the following to your HTML within the `img` tag:

```
<img title='<%# Eval ("ProductDescription") %>'
```

Comment: Hi - I haven't inserted each image manually. They are all called/loaded from the DB using a stored procedure - how does that work? Sorry I am have pretty limited knowledge

Comment: Is the page generated from code? A loop that generates one of the above tables for each image? If so, you would edit the code to include something like `@"title=""" + thisRecord.ProductDescription + """" ` in that code.

Comment: While we're on the subject, learn to use `div`s rather than `table`s. Yes, they're a pain to learn up front and less intuitive than tables, but you'll be thankful when your boss says this page has to be responsive on a smartphone. Again, the Bootstrap framework has some [helpful tools](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) to make things the right width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the mouse over on the image you will be able to see the description:

```
   <asp:Image runat="server"  ToolTip="Description of your Product"/>
```